# CSS validation class not applied

Tags: html, css

I'm doing this to set a border around input fields:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea { border: 1px solid #9BAF31;}
```

I have client-side validation that adds this class when errors occur:

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

But only the background is set. The border is still the original color. How can i set it with the validation color?

Comment: your first declaration probably overrides your second. how about border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important ? it would also be better if you provided a sample in jsfiddle to better diagnose this

Comment: `!important` is a one shot sledgehammer, it is best avoided as it often leads to "I wish there was a double !important method" situations. Get the specificity right instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
input[type=text].input-validation-error ,input[type=password].input-validation-error, textarea.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the rule you want to apply at least as [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) as the existing rules.

Comment: in this case how do i make it at least as specific?

Comment: Follow the link to see the rules for specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the .input-validation-error above the "input[type=text],input[type=password], textarea". Also, what does FireBug says when you inspect the element?